# Scattering amplitude of strong interactions, Euler's Beta function and strings

Tags: string-theory, mathematical-physics, history

On reading [the answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/28226/191528) by [Ron Maimon](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/4864/ron-maimon) to the "[Gabriele Veneziano, strong nuclear force and beta-function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28211/gabriele-veneziano-strong-nuclear-force-and-beta-function)" I became puzzled: Why the fact of the Beta function implication leads to the idea of a string underlying?
Would you be so kind as to elucidate what the Beta function has to do with a string?

Comment: From beta to string, it was a gap of like 2 years of intense mathematics with very little physics.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-does-Eulers-beta-function-lead-to-string-theory/answer/Ron-Maimon?share=4984dbde&srid=3atOC And whom did we find here... @Ron Maimon again! Hats off to this fellow !